# Website won't scroll or zoom on iphone. NodeJS canvas project

Tags: iphone, html, node.js, scroll

I have a problem that I've been working on for the past 10 hours (going crazy).

I've been working on a revised version of Walma - which is a collaborative white board written for node.js. I have placed a div header above the whiteboard, and a content area and footer div below it.

This works perfectly on my pc, however when I try to run it on my iPhone I can not scroll down the page to view content. It's like there is no permission to do this- I can not scroll or zoom or anything apart from draw on the canvas.

Notes: I have made the canvas only take up 60% of the iphone screen so that I am able to scroll (as apposed to draw). But this doesn't work.
I have removed the meta tags that you see in the demo.
I have changed the css multiple times with no success.

Is there something I'm over looking? Is there some javascript that's preventing iphone from scrolling that I haven't noticed? I would be incredibly thankful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Git (demo is linked in the description top) : https://github.com/opinsys/walma

My adaptation : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/91956067/walma.tar.gz

Many Many thanks,

Joel.