# Fix the zoom in on phone

Tags: html, css, node.js

I have created a website using node js and html. When i look at the website on my phone, I have to zoom in in order to see it. Is there any code I can put in my css where I can fix the website content to adjust to the size of the window/browser?

```
  /*Styles the Webpage*/

h1 {
    color:black;
    font-family: Georgia;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 35px;
}

label {
    position: relative;
  float: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: black;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width: 5em;  height: 1.5em;
      align: center;
}
input[type=number] {
    width: 8em;  height: 1.5em;
}
div {

      border: 1px solid black;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 25px;

    }
body {
    background-color:#c7c9c7    ;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;

}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #8a8d8f;
}

.active {
background-color:#002B7F    ;
}
img {
    position: fixed;
    width: 190px;
    height:50px;
    left: 40px;
  top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help you but I found [Website won't scroll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16610251/website-wont-scroll-or-zoom-on-iphone-nodejs-canvas-project) . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your website responsive. This you can do it with [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) and add to head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code into the `<head>` tag:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It will cause every device to show the real pixel sizes of your elements.

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly! however, now my image is not adjusting. Any idea how i can get the image size to adjust also?

Comment: Well, that's the whole big theme of *responsive web design* - which can't be explained with a few words only. Anyway, i don't know your code, so I can't give you any answers beyond that. Just a tip:  Use percentage values for widths, that already does a lot making code responsive.

Comment: i put my css code above. Maybe you can help out a bit?

Comment: I can't answer - I have no idea where that img is in your HTML and what you want to do with it. But as I said: Try to use a percentage value for its width - maybe that brings you one steo closer to the solution.

Comment: Is there css code where I can make it so text does not go over the image but rather just moves down if the browser size is changed?? This would solve my problem.